# Curl loses body when a POST redirected from http to https

Tags: post, redirect, curl

I'm trying to use curl 7.23.1 to POST some data to my server (which runs an `nginx` server). When this `nginx` is queried using `http://`, it redirects to `https://` if it can (if it has keys and all the mambo-jumbo)

It looks like curl is doing something... odd. For compatibility reasons, my script (the thing that runs `curl`) is sending its requests to `http://`, but when it hits a server that has `https://` available (and therefore, gets redirected), the body in the `POST` request disappears.

I'm trying to upload a bunch of text using [--data-urlencode name@filename](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) option. Basically, I run an script, dump its output in the file `/tmp/checkin/cmd_result`, and I want to upload that as the "data" attribute of the request:

```
curl --max-time 30 --silent --location-trusted \
     --insecure --write-out "%{http_code}" --request POST \
     --data-urlencode "data@/tmp/checkin/cmd_result" \
     "http:/myserver/command_reply?command_id=524729ce93bc63292c1c9831" \
     --trace-ascii /tmp/command_response_trace.log \
     --output /tmp/checkin/cmd_res_resp --connect-timeout 10
```

But the redirection seems to strip the body. If I send my data directly to `https://`, everything works like a charm. Adding `-L` (`--location`) or `--location-trusted` to the curl instruction doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Has someone experienced the same issue? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

PS:

This is the trace `curl` outputs (I've cleaned it a bit):

```
=> Send header, 300 bytes (0x12c)
0000: POST /command_reply?&command_id=52
0040: 4729ce93bc63292c1c9831 HTTP/1.1
0061: User-Agent: curl/7.23.1 (mips-openwrt-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.23.1 
00a1: OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7
00e4: Content-Length: 356
00f9: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
012a: 
=> Send data, 356 bytes (0x164)
0000: data=PING%20google.coms%0A
<= Recv header, 32 bytes (0x20)
0000: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Server: nginx/1.1.19
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Sat, 28 Sep 2013 19:11:27 GMT
<= Recv header, 25 bytes (0x19)
0000: Content-Type: text/html
<= Recv header, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: Content-Length: 161
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive
<= Recv header, 120 bytes (0x78)
0000: Location: https://myserver/sensor/command_reply?command_id
0040: =524729ce93bc63292c1c9831
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 161 bytes (0xa1)
0000: <html>
0008: <head><title>302 Found</title></head>
002f: <body bgcolor="white">
0047: <center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
006c: <hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
008f: </body>
0098: </html>
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
=> Send SSL data, 189 bytes (0xbd)
0000: .....
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
<= Recv SSL data, 90 bytes (0x5a)
0000: .....
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
<= Recv SSL data, 3227 bytes (0xc9b)
0000: .....?.
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
<= Recv SSL data, 525 bytes (0x20d)
0000: .^~...
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
<= Recv SSL data, 4 bytes (0x4)
0000: ....
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
=> Send SSL data, 134 bytes (0x86)
0000: ...'
== Info: SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
=> Send SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
=> Send SSL data, 16 bytes (0x10)
0000: ....
== Info: SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
<= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
<= Recv SSL data, 16 bytes (0x10)
0000: ...
=> Send header, 230 bytes (0xe6)
0000: POST /sensor/command_reply?command_id=52
0040: 4729ce93bc63292c1c9831 HTTP/1.1
0061: User-Agent: curl/7.23.1 (mips-openwrt-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.23.1 
00a1: OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7
00bc: Host: myserver
00d7: Accept: */*
00e4: 
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Server: nginx/1.1.19
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Sat, 28 Sep 2013 19:11:27 GMT
<= Recv header, 47 bytes (0x2f)
0000: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 20 bytes (0x14)
0000: Content-Length: 22
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: {"r": 200, "data": {}}
== Info: SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
=> Send SSL data, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: ..
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like your nginx does a 302 redirect from http to https. Based on RFC2616 standard, you should use 301 or 307 redirect in your nginx config. See more information from the link below.

Note that some user agents (chrome, firefox, IE) went further and treat a 302 redirect as a GET request even though the original request could be a POST.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

> Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed
>         to change the method on the redirected request.  However, most
>         existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303
>         response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless
>         of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have
>         been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which
>         kind of reaction is expected of the client.

**Update**

301 might not work as well. Find this in curl manual. Looks like curl violates RFC2616 as well. So you might want to try 307 first.

> When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain  GET
>                 (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with
>                 a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response
>                 code  was  any  other  3xx code, curl will re-send the following
>                 request using the same unmodified method.

Comment: Interesting... I'll tell the person who manages the server and I'll let you know. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: My understanding is that curl should also send a GET request after receiving the 302 response. Could you remove this option `--request POST` in your command and see if curl sends the 2nd request as a GET request? Because you have the `--data-urlencode` option, curl should send the first request as a POST anyway. My guess is that `--request POST` might force curl to send both requests as post.

Comment: Yeah, if you're curious, it was a problem with the Nginx server handling all this. I don't know all the details (yet) but I know it was a routing problem.

Comment: 307 worked well. 301 doesn't works, it redirected POST request as GET.